# What is the formula for ripple factor of the filters?

Tags: filter, rectifier

In some books I find the formula for the ripple factors of filters (like LC and RC) to whome rectifier are connected at input as

Ripple factor = Vr.m.s/Vdc

While in other books

Ripple factor = Peak to peak voltage/Vdc

Which is the correct formula?

Comment: Generally, we define the "cleanliness" of a DC power supply's output by its peak-to-peak ripple (and sometimes with noise as well). From this standpoint \$r=V_{ac-pp}/V_{DC}\$ makes sense. However, almost all of the lectures/textbooks I had a look into define the ripple factor as \$r=V_{ac-rms}/V_{DC}\$. Maybe the definition is context-dependent.